# How to figure out which button I'm pressing

Tags: android, c#

I'm working on an app, that I'm trying to get to work on a android device that has additional buttons.

The device is called a BH95, from BATL. It has 4 side buttons(1 volume up, 1 power button, 2 unknown), 3 regular android buttons on the face(Home, Return, the running app list), and 6 additional face buttons below the screen. 4 of those 6, are D-pad buttons. The two other are F1 and F2.

While running a test app to determine what the keys are actually called, (A simple OnKeyDown override that posts a toast and I can just use a breakpoint on), I've found that the 2 unknown side buttons and the F1 and F2 don't trigger the OnKeyDown code, so I can't figure out what the keyCode for them is, if they even have one, and aren't handled in some weird way.

My question is, how would I figure out what the buttons are called, or how to handle them?

Also, the lock/power button also doesn't trigger the keydown, neither do the home or list running app buttons, but the Return button and Volume up do.

ps. It doesn't have a volume down, instead overflowing the volume control when you press volume at max volume, muting the device, with an additional press setting volume to lowest non-muted.

App is a Xamarin App in VS2019

Answer (score 1):

Actually found out what the keys were using the logcat in the Android Device Monitor.
F1,F2,F3 and F5, for those curious.